# Can I control labels when using RadioButtonLists?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, radiobuttonlist

This

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("London","1"));
    RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Paris", "2"));
}
```

and this

```
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
   </asp:RadioButtonList></div>
```

produce HTML something like this

```
   <input id="RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="1" />
   <label for="RadioButtonList1_0">London</label>
   <input id="RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="2" />
   <label for="RadioButtonList1_1">Paris</label>
```

but what I really want is this, **note the class in the `<label>` tag.**

```
    <input type="radio" name="Event" id="whatever" value="1" /> 
    <label for="London" class="London">London</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="Event" id="whatever" value="2" /> 
    <label for="Paris" class="Paris">Paris</label>
```

Can I add a cssClass to the automatically generated `<label>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inherit from `RadioButtonList`, like shown [here](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2007/03/10/Customizing-RadioButtonList.aspx) or [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1270171.aspx).

The last link is probably more in line with what you want.

You should only need to override the RenderItem method, like so:

```
protected override void RenderItem(ListItemType itemType, int repeatIndex, RepeatInfo repeatInfo, HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
    radioButton.Page = this.Page;
    radioButton.GroupName = this.UniqueID;
    radioButton.ID = this.ClientID + "_" + repeatIndex.ToString();
    radioButton.Text = this.Items[repeatIndex].Text;            
    radioButton.Attributes["value"] = this.Items[repeatIndex].Value;
    radioButton.Checked = this.Items[repeatIndex].Selected;
    radioButton.TextAlign = this.TextAlign;
    radioButton.AutoPostBack = this.AutoPostBack;
    radioButton.TabIndex = this.TabIndex;
    radioButton.Enabled = this.Enabled;

    radioButton.CssClass = InnerCssClass;
    radioButton.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, this.Items[repeatIndex].Text);

    radioButton.RenderControl(writer);

    // add new label
    Label radioLabel = new Label();
    radioLabel.Text = this.Items[repeatIndex].Text;
    radioLabel.CssClass = this.Items[repeatIndex].Text;
    radioLabel.AssociatedControlID = this.ClientID + "_" + repeatIndex.ToString();
    radioLabel.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

Note, I have not actually compiled above code, but should be enough to guide you in a proper direction :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an ASP.NET pro, but I do know that you can easily control the presentation of the LABEL's inside your an element with a known ID by using child selectors.

```
#myElementID LABEL {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that is an idea I may put forward, but designers can be so fussy :D